# ffmpeg leaves audio gap when concatening videos

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to cut a video in 2 parts then reassembling with ffmpeg but the final output has a small audio glitch right where the segments meet. I am using the following command to split the video 1.mp4 in 2 parts:

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:02 -async 1 1-1.mp4

and

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:02 -t 00:00:02 -async 1 1-2.mp4

Once I have the 2 parts I am concatening them back together with:

> ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4

files.txt is correctly listing both files. Can anyone point me to where the problem might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The glitch is likely due to the audio [priming sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFAppenG/QTFFAppenG.html) showing up in between.

Since you're re-encoding the segments, you can do this in one command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex 
                "[0]trim=duration=2[v1];[0]trim=2:4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];
                 [0]atrim=duration=2[a1];[0]atrim=2:4,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
                 [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks Mulvya. I ran this command and it created a 4 seconds video out of my original 6s video without any audio gap. I think I understand what audio priming sample is but I don't understand the parameters of your command. Can you please explain or tell me how to adapt this command to use as source 1-1.mp4 and 1-2.mp4?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: First, I split the video stream of the source twice: `trim=duration=2` means start from `0` and split a 2 second segment. `trim=2:4` means split from `t=2` to `t=4`. I do the same with the audio using the audio versions of the filters. Then I use the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-3) filter to join these parts together. I wouldn't recommend going through the intermediate files route (`1-1.mp4, 1-2.mp4`) unless you need to.

Comment: And the setpts filters are to reset the timestamps of the cut segments. Needed due to how FFmpeg in general works.

Comment: Well, I really have to go the intermediate files. because the true purpose of this code is to concatenate several files in order. Imagine my user can choose from different scenes to build his final video, that's what I intend to do.

Comment: Could this answer please be updated?  It's been 2 years and still no actual answers to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for about 3 weeks. 
just merge the mp3 files using `sox`

```
sox in1.mp3 in2.mp3 in3.mp3 out.mp3
```

When I used concat with `FFMPEG` it made 12.5ms (I saw them on using `Audacity`) audio gaps. (I don't know why)

Maybe for your case it'll be better to extract the audio and video to two separate files using ffmpeg, merge them (video using FFMPEG and audio using sox) then put the files together into one container (mp4) file

Answer (score 0):

I run into this myself and the problem was that one audio was at 44kHz and the other at 48kHz. Once I made both at the same sample rate, the problem was solved